# Ruby i18n.translate having :raise => true as default behaviour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-i18n, i18n-gem

When i call:

```
t 'to_translate'
```

method from my template, I would like it to raise an error without actually passing second parameter like this:

```
t 'to_translate', :raise => true
```

It would save me a lot of typing in every translation I do. Or is there a workaround for this?

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the answer on the [I18n documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) paragraph 6.2

"[..] the default exception handling does not allow to catch missing translations during automated tests easily. For this purpose a different exception handler can be specified. The specified exception handler must be a method on the I18n module or a class with #call method:

```
module I18n
  class JustRaiseExceptionHandler < ExceptionHandler
    def call(exception, locale, key, options)
      if exception.is_a?(MissingTranslation)
        raise exception.to_exception
      else
        super
      end
    end
  end
end

I18n.exception_handler = I18n::JustRaiseExceptionHandler.new
```

This would re-raise only the MissingTranslationData exception, passing all other input to the default exception handler."

Learn more on
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#using-different-exception-handlers